# Ajax PHP and Cookie and Redirect

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, redirect

We have a page... where we ask user for an email address. once they drop in the email and hit submit.
We want to submit that info via Ajax to a php file that will take the email and find out their Name from the database table.... Once done. Insert the name into cookie and redirect to next page and then access the cookie value on next page.

Any tips??

Comment: How did you tried and failed ?

Answer (score 1):

I could be reading the question wrong, but I don't think you need AJAX to perform this task. Using forms, you can send information (like the user's email) to another page via the submit command. On the next page you can perform the PHP query based on the POST data. You will also have the data without needing to pull it from a cookie, or you could set a cookie using this data.